# Factory Pattern Understanding

Tags: c#

I have implementated the Factory Pattern as below.

However, since the individual classes are public, nothing prevents someone from instantiating them directly.

Is this correct? How do I ensure that the concrete classes are only created via the Factory?

```
namespace MRS.Framework
{
    public  abstract class DataSource
    {
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "DataSource";
        }
    }

    public class XMLDataSource : DataSource
    {

    }

    public class SqlDataSource : DataSource
    {

    }

    public class CSVDataSource : DataSource
    {
        public int MyProperty { get; set; }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return "CSVDataSource";
        }
    }
}
```

Factory implementation

```
namespace MRS.Framework
{
    public abstract class DataSourceFactory
    {
        public abstract DataSource CreateDataSource(DataSourceType datasourcetype);
    }

    public class CSVDataSourceFactory : DataSourceFactory
    {
        public CSVDataSourceFactory()
        {

        }
        public override DataSource CreateDataSource(DataSourceType datasourcetype)
        {
            return new CSVDataSource();
        }
    }


    public class XMLDataSourceFactory : DataSourceFactory
    {
        public override DataSource CreateDataSource(DataSourceType datasourcetype)
        {
            return new XMLDataSource();
        }
    }

    public class SqlDataSourceFactory : DataSourceFactory
    {
        public override DataSource CreateDataSource(DataSourceType datasourcetype)
        {
            return new SqlDataSource();
        }
    }

}
```

Main

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            DataSourceFactory datasourcefactory = new CSVDataSourceFactory();
            CSVDataSource ds = (CSVDataSource)datasourcefactory.CreateDataSource(DataSourceType.CSVDataSource);
            CSVDataSource myds = new CSVDataSource();
            Console.WriteLine(ds.ToString());
            Console.WriteLine(myds.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
```

Comment: What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if it would be easier for everyone if people wrote questions in their native language and someone with good english translated it.

Comment: He's referring to the fact that the current class definitions would allow someone to create the specific data sources directly rather than only through the factory.

Comment: @YoryeNathan true but soem times ppl wiv nglish asa native language mak moer ofa mes off it then he did

Comment: I've updated the question to hopefully reflect the original asker's intent. You guys can correct it if you feel it isn't right.

Comment: @RhysW There's got to be enough people that speak good english and can also understand the messy ones and those who aren't too good in english so that SO could add some sort of translation tool.

Comment: @YoryeNathan or a simple grammatical and spelling test when signing up and if you fail you are assigned a translator XD or directed towards english lessons...

Comment: @RhysW I like the "assigned a translator" idea.

Comment: @Josh I think you really got what he was trying to ask. Good job! And good question as well.

Comment: @YoryeNathan though id hate to be that poor sucker spending all day just rewriting peoples questions so others can understand it

Comment: @RhysW You'd get good rep for it

Comment: @YoryeNathan Would sell his soul if he got enough rep for it =p

Comment: @yoryeNathan but how would you ensure the edits were of good quality? otherwise people would jsut edit them for no reason, or to poor quality for the sake of rep and lol Servy XD

Comment: @Servy I don't chase rep. I fight for best answer.

Comment: @RhysW Then the rep will come in the form of upvotes for a translation, just as a question. You'll be able to up/down vote the trans just as you can with the original question. Rep goes to the appropriate guy.

Comment: Guys, Meta would be a better place to have this discussion; the comments are intended for clarifying the question at hand, not talking about tangential issues.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, your intuition here is correct; if you want to restrict the construction of your `CSVDataSourceFactory` class then you have your access modifiers wrong.

However, it's not the access modifier of the class you need to fix, it's the access modifier of the *constructor*. You should mark the default constructor `internal` so that only other classes within your assembly can construct them. You will, of course, have to enforce your own rules within that assembly but since you have complete control over that code, it shouldn't be an issue.

```
public class XMLDataSource : DataSource
{
  internal XMLDataSource() { }
}

public class SqlDataSource : DataSource
{
  internal SqlDataSource() { }
}

public class CSVDataSource : DataSource
{
  public int MyProperty { get; set; }

  internal CSVDataSource() { }

  public override string ToString()
  {
      return "CSVDataSource";
  }
}
```

Comment: This should be noted in simple words: Put all the Factory-Classes and the Factory class in the same project, and don't let anything else be in that project.

Comment: This definetly helped me.Would like to know what is the standard form of Factory Pattern with respect to access specifiers?

Comment: There are a few different styles, depending on your needs. What you have is not uncommon, once you "hide" the constructors for the concrete classes. Another common pattern is given in @Servy's answer : make your concrete classes `internal` but implement a `public interface` that your factory returns. WCF uses a variation of this, with `protected` classes nested inside the factory class itself (e.g. `HttpChannelFactory.CreateChannel()` returns a `new HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel()`) I've got a blog post in the pipeline about this, but its unfortunately a few weeks away.

Comment: ok thanks , update me , will be interested in reading that blog thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know how to prevent people from being able to create instances of the datasources you can do it through interfaces.  Create an interface for each datasource with all of the method that you want it to expose.  Make the class itself internal or a private inner class of the factory (internal is usually appropriate) and the interface public.

If the question is not how to stop people from creating instances but if you should, that's more of a subjective answer.  There are a few things to consider:

1. What are the consequences of someone bypassing the factor and creating their own datasource?  Nothing bad?  Poorer performance?  Major security violation?  If they're only shooting themselves in the foot or hurting nothing, maybe you don't need to bother to stop them.
2. How hard is it to stop them?  Do you need to prevent them from using reflection to access the underlying class?  Is using an interface layer sufficient?
3. How trustworty are your users?  Is it just an internal app for your own use or for use on your own team?  Is it being shipped to thousands of other people?  A small internal use app might not bother, a large scale one needs to assume there are either really malicious or ignorant users and what you expose will matter significantly.  It is also important to improve usability in general as the userbase grows.